# Could not resolve library project after upgrade to Android 3.0 beta 2

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to upgrade my AS to latest beta2 and encounter following issues for my `app` and `lib` modules.

In my `app` `build.gradle` I have 2 flavors

```
    flavorDimensions "default" 
       productFlavors {
           stage {
             applicationId "com.mycompany.hello.stage"
             resValue "string", "app_name", "Stage"
            }
           production {
            applicationId "com.mycompany.hello.stage.production"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Live"
            }
      }
```

And I specify that the app will talk only to specific type of my `lib` as following:

```
 stageCompile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'debug')
 productionCompile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'release')
```

`lib` `build.gradle` file I have only build types and no flavor block

```
 publishNonDefault true
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix ".debug"
    }
    release {
        versionNameSuffix ".release"
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

Above code to my best knowledge that `app` will depends on the build variant and talk to particular build variants of `lib`. It works perfectly until I upgraded to AS 3.0.

here is the gradle error message...I am not sure if this was caused by `flavorDimensions` mismatches in my two gradle files.

```
Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileStageDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:stageDebugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :lib.
 Required by project :app
> Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'stageCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :lib.
```

Answer (score 0):

So I spent couple of hours and migrated my project to match the migrating guide provided my [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html).

I end up doing following changes to achieve what I want:

`app` variant `productionRelease` should invoke `lib` `release`

`app` variant `stageDebug` should invoke `lib` `debug`

app build.gradle file

```
flavorDimensions "default" //add this line for flavorDimensions 
productFlavors {
    stage {
        ...
    }

    production {
        ...
    }
}
implementation project(':lib')
```

In my lib build.gradle I remain the same

```
publishNonDefault true
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix ".debug"
    }
    release {
        versionNameSuffix ".release"
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

The only catch I have here is to ignore certain variants I don't want to achieve productionRelease(app)+release(lib) and stageDebug(app)+debug(lib) combinations.

// In this way I will only have `productionRelease` and `stageDebug` variant left in AS panel for me.

In app build.gradle

```
variantFilter { variant ->
    def names = variant.flavors*.name
    if (names.contains("stage") && variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        variant.ignore = true
    }
    if (names.contains("production") && variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
        variant.ignore = true
    }
}
```

When I switch build variants of my `app`, it will also switch my `lib` to corresponding build type.

I am still no sure if this is the best practice. If you guys find a better way to do it. Please do let me know.